# Show the sum of data if there is only data on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]I want show data if there is not empty. My query is :

```
SELECT     t.idtest,
           t.testkhusus,
           t.biayakhusus,
           t.uangmuka,
           t.total,
           t.tanggallunas,
           t.biayatambahan,
           p.namaperusahaan,
           (Sum(jth.tarifpsikolog) + Sum(jth.tarifadministrasi) + Sum(jth.tariftester)) AS biayadll
FROM       test t
INNER JOIN perusahaan p
ON         t.perusahaan_idperusahaan=p.idperusahaan
INNER JOIN (jadwaltest jt
INNER JOIN jadwaltest_has_biayatimelostcost jth
ON         jt.idjadwaltest = jth.idjadwaltest)
ON         t.idtest = jt.test_idtest
WHERE      t.tanggallunas BETWEEN '2018-05-22' AND '2018-05-23'
```

If the blank data should not show the line.

I want the result of mysql_num_rows () is 0 instead of 1.

Please help,, thank you..[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: Please put some effort into formatting your query.

Comment: how i can to that..

Comment: Your query is invalid because you are mixing columns and `SUM` in your select clause.

Comment: if I do not use the date (BETWEEN) the request runs correctly, but if using date where date no data then the request was problematic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define you aggregating column in `GROUP BY`.

Check my simple fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cae193/5

```
select SUM(amount) 
from t1
where 0=1;

select SUM(amount) 
from t1
where 0=1
group by id
```

In first scenario it returns empty row with `null`s even if there is nothing to summarize.

But in second one with `GROUP BY` it returns no rows.

In your case that could be `GROUP BY t.idtest` or whatever you want and/or you need